# Issue with excel if or statement?

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, conditional-statements

From the following:

```
=IF(A2<100, "1", IF(OR(A2>=101, A2<=800), "2", IF(OR(A2>=801, A2<=1000), "3")))
```

when inputting a number, I can only get the outputs of `1` and `2`. `3` will not be output if I input a number ranging from 801-1000. Anyone understand why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this one instead:

```
=IF(A2<100, "1", IF(AND(A2>=101, A2<=800), "2", IF(AND(A2>=801, A2<=1000), "3")))
```

also if `A2` is `100` formula returns `FALSE`. Maybe you need to change `A2<100` to `A2<=100`?

Answer (score 1):

You can actually make the formula shorter as well, if you use something like this:

```
=IF(A2<100, "1", IF(A2<=800, "2", IF(A2<=1000, "3")))
```

That's assuming that there are no breaking points in the allowed range (re the issue with `A2<=100` and if decimals are allowed (e.g. 800.5 would currently return `FALSE` with your formula, but will return `3` with the above one).

Or use a defined table for lookup purposes and then use `VLOOKUP` or `INDEX`/`MATCH` to get the corresponding values for the inserted values in cell A2 (this is particularly useful if you have a lot of different ranges for which there is to be different results).

Also note that in the above, you will be getting text values because of the quotes. If you need numeric values, remove them.

Answer (score 0):

`LOOKUP` is another option, e.g. assuming A2 is a positive number

`=LOOKUP(A2,{0,101,801,1001},{1,2,3,"Out of range"})`